# How to push a specific page on notification tap flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this package [awsome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications), although its working both in foreground and background, when application is killed it only opens the app,it doesn't push the assigned page.

Listening to notification streams up in main() function

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final AwesomeNotifications awesomeNotifications = AwesomeNotifications();
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  awesomeNotifications.initialize('resource://drawable/splash', [
    NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        channelName: 'Basic notifications',
        channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
        defaultColor: kPrimaryColor,
        ledColor: Colors.white)
  ]);

  await awesomeNotifications.isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
    if (!isAllowed) {
      AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
    }
  });

  await awesomeNotifications.actionStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
    if (receivedNotification.id == 0) {
      navigatorKey.currentState!
          .pushNamed('/notification', arguments: receivedNotification.payload);
    }
    if (receivedNotification.id == 1) {
      navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('/secondary_notification',
          arguments: receivedNotification.payload);
    }
  });

...

  runApp(MyApp(token: token));
}
```

I am I missing some thing here??